# Consuming an API from a Salesforce Commerce Cloud controller

Tags: api, salesforce-commerce-cloud

Inside a SFCC custom controller, at a certain point I need to consume an API and wait for its response before continuing. In fact, the my controller's response depends on the API's response itself.

Unless I'm mistaken, the SFCC documentation doesn't provide any code sample about that.

Express apparently provides a solution (see the very beginning of https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-express/ for example), but SFCC middleware doesn't seem to handle the `async` keyword when defining a request handler.

Can anybody help on this one?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide more information? For example, how is this controller being called, what kind of API it is, etc?

Comment: This controller should be the action executed after a checkout form's subsission in an e-commerce website. From the controller, both an Internet Payment Provider and an Order Management System should be called via APIs.
By the way, problems start when I'm trying to use the `fetch()` method, either in a controller or in a hook. My IDE complains (_Unresolved function or method fetch()_), whereas my browser throws an error (_ReferenceError: "fetch" is not defined in controller Test_)...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to handle async code on SFCC natively.
And you need to change your code's structure according to this restriction.
But you can use some jobs as a workaround.

Please check this link for more information about this concept:
https://medium.com/@osapishchuk/asynchronous-execution-within-sfcc-9cc6226e1ac6